# How to extract num part of a string

Tags: php

I have a string like "My String 2" and I like to get only num value "2".
I try to do that you see below but result is egal to 0.

```
$AlphaSURV1="My String 2";
$NumSURV1=intval($AlphaSURV1);
echo $NumSURV1;
```

Can you help me to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: If you have a string `"3 some text 5"`, do you want spaces preserved or not?

Comment: If string is like "3 some text 5", I want to get "5". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture the last group of digits in a string, you can use a regular expression:

```
$str = "123 test 29";
preg_match("/[0-9]+$/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]); # 29
```

This work correctly for all the following cases, including lack of whitespace, leading digits and multiple digits at the end of the string:

```
"1"        => 1
"test 2"   => 2
"test 34"  => 34
"5 test 6" => 6
"7test8"   => 8
```

Note that if you simply want to get the last character in the string and treat it like a number you can use the following:

```
$str = "My String 2";

$digit = intval(substr($str, -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip out the non-numeric characters with a regular expression which matches non-digits:

```
$NumSURV1 = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $AlphaSURV1);
```

Well, your comment on your original post makes this answer kind of invalid.  If you put `"3 some text 5"` into the `preg_replace()` answer I gave, you'll get `"35"`, not just `"5"`.  If I take a wild guess and assume you just want the last chunk of text out of the string instead of all the numbers, and assuming there are spaces, you should do this:

```
$exp = explode(" ", $AlphaSURV1);
$NumSURV1 = $exp[count($exp) - 1];
```

Which is ugly, but it will split your input string on spaces and give you the last element in the resulting array.

A prettier way of doing the second answer, thanks to @nickb:

```
$exp = explode(" ", $AlphaSURV1);
$NumSURV1 = end($exp);
```

(incidentally, you *could* do `$NumSURV1 = end(explode(" ", $AlphaSURV1));` as it works, but you'll get a `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference` error if you have strict checking enabled on your server)

Comment: You can also do `$NumSURV1 = end( $exp);`

Comment: @nickb I should really take the time to go back through the PHP function list some day, I didn't even realize that function existed.  Thanks.

Comment: This will only work if the digit is between `0` and `9`. For strings like `"test 29"` will only result in the `9` being captured.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as "point whoring" here. This is not Reddit.

Comment: @meagar The `preg_replace` removes any non-integer characters in the string, so for the string `"test 29"` it would absolutely return `"29"`.

Comment: @Crontab in your *first* example, it would work correctly for `"test 29"`, but as you indicated, incorrectly for `"3 test 5"`. Your later example will not work for `"test 29"`. Neither of your solutions will work correctly for all cases.

Comment: @meagar Not to argue about it, but both of my solutions work fine for `"test 29"`, thanks.  Try them and see.  Given the lack of information from the asker, the first answer was sufficient.  Because of a question asked in the comments, I added my second answer.  Without knowledge of the data to be parse besides the two examples above, my second answer was sufficient.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read closely enough and assumed you were just taking the last character. That said, it won't work for `"test29"` or `"test 29 "` or `"test\29"` or any number of other cases.